# Fetching the zip code value from XML & match the zipcode of CSV file & display the corresponding sort code of csv to .zpl file

Tags: c#, xml, csv

I have a xml file from which I have extracted the data of zipcode :

```
newShippingLabel.Consignee.Zip = shipment.Consignee.Address.PostalCode;
```

I have  a CSV file having 2 columns:

```
ZipCode Sort Code
49801   12
49802   12
49858   15
49870   12
49876   12
49938   13
50001   20
```

so on..

If `Consignee.Zip = 49801` then I need to fetch a sort code value from csv against that zip code i.e 49801 -> as 12 & store it in SortCode variable.
which I have defined :

```
public string SortCode { get; set;}
```

I need a code for this

Answer (score 0):

Use my CSVReader below.  It will read the CSV into a datatable which will make it easy to use linq to lookup zip code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.csv";
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader();
            DataSet ds = csvReader.ReadCSVFile(FILENAME, true);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Table1"];
        }
    }
    public class CSVReader
    {

        public DataSet ReadCSVFile(string fullPath, bool headerRow)
        {

            string path = fullPath.Substring(0, fullPath.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
            string filename = fullPath.Substring(fullPath.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(fullPath))
                {
                    string ConStr = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0}" + ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR={1};FMT=Delimited\\\"", path, headerRow ? "Yes" : "No");
                    string SQL = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", filename);
                    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(SQL, ConStr);
                    adapter.Fill(ds, "TextFile");
                    ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Table1";
                }
                foreach (DataColumn col in ds.Tables["Table1"].Columns)
                {
                    col.ColumnName = col.ColumnName.Replace(" ", "_");
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            return ds;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ways you can do.

Write CSV parser yourself, cache the zipcode - sortcode data in dictionary

```
var zipSortCodeDict = File.ReadAllLines("zipCodes.csv").ToDictionary(line => line.Split("  ")[0], line => line.Split("  ")[1]);
```

Then easy access to them as below

```
//get the sort code
string zipCode = "49876";
string sortCode = zipSortCodeDict[zipCode];
```

If the CSV file gets complex, you can use external library for loading CSV file and cache them as dictionary. Then you can access the sort code easily.

This is one library you can do easily with CSV parsing, Cinchoo ETL - an open source framework

```
var zipSortCodeDict = new ChoCSVReader("zipCodes.csv").WithDelimiter("   ").WithFirstLineHeader().ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.ZipCode, kvp => kvp.SortCode);

//get the sort code
string zipCode = "49876";
string sortCode = zipSortCodeDict[zipCode];
```

Disclosure: I'm the author of this library